# Why does the message in the error handling routine get printed twice?

Tags: excel, vba, exception, error-handling

I realize that the sub should be exited before reaching the errorhandler through normal flow but I tested what would happen if it did not and the result surprised me.

```
Sub error_test()


On Error GoTo errorhandler

Err.Raise (7)
MsgBox "one"

errorhandler:
MsgBox "two"
Resume Next

End Sub
```

prints "two", "one", "two", "two"

why does the "two" get printed twice in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes it a bit clearer:

```
Sub error_test()

    On Error GoTo errorhandler

    Err.Raise (7)
    Debug.Print "one"

errorhandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, "two"
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Output:

```
 7            two
one
 0            two
 20           two
```

The first time it enters the error handling block it's because of the `Err.Raise`, the second time it just falls into it right after the `MsgBox` call, and the third time it's the `Resume Next` which triggers it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/resume-without-error-error-20

You can't use `Resume Next` if you're not currently handling an error.

Comment: that explains why its printed once after "one" is printed but not twice. I was expecting it to print once

Comment: when I include exit sub it prints "two", "one" then stops

Answer (score 1):

You should have an Exit Sub before your error handler.

Otherwise it runs, hitting the "Two" after the raise and then back into the proc hitting the "One".

Then it goes into the error handler in normal execution and hits the "Two" again.

After that it tries to run the Resume command, which is an error as it isn't in error mode. As there is an error handler it goes into the error handler and outputs the "Two" an extra time. This time it can Resume and is at the bottom of the procedure.